# how does asp.net know what event was fired?

Tags: asp.net, events

I know about the viewstate and dopostback and everything, I just don't know where the reference to the fired event goes. Say, button1.click is fired, then when the page goes through the postback cycle, and then page.load is executed, then the raised event must be executed, but how does asp.net know which event it was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content posted with request that is made when you click a button for example, contains the name of the control that raised the event. In the following, I used an HTTP Headers reader tool that shows the information sent in an HTTP request and checked the requests sent by clicking two buttons on a Web Form. Each request has a different value set for Button= in the post data under content.

```
http://localhost:1182/Pages/NewFolder1/WebForm1.aspx

POST /Pages/NewFolder1/WebForm1.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 548
__VIEWSTATE=viewstateblahblah&__EVENTVALIDATION=eventblahblah&**Button2=Button**
[..omitted parts for brevity..]
----------------------------------------------------------
http://localhost:1182/Pages/NewFolder1/WebForm1.aspx

POST /Pages/NewFolder1/WebForm1.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 548
__VIEWSTATE=blah blah state&__EVENTVALIDATION=viewstateblahblah&**Button1=Button**
[..omitted parts for brevity..]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update:** To augment my answer, consider the following content that is posted to the server when two events are sent to the server at the same time (e.g. a Button.Click and
a ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged). 
_*VIEWSTATE=view state encrypted blah blah &*_EVENTVALIDATION=event validation encrypted blah blah&DropDownList1=Three&Button1=Button

So the form is built in a way that event information is added to the HTTP request that is posted to the server. The parameters contain the names of the controls that rose the event and I think all of this is encrypted in the __EVENTVALIDATION parameter that makes sure that no tampering occured in the events that were raised and the controls that raised them. Its like a hash of the event information.

Comment: The ID of the button clicked is not transmitted to the server via VIEWSTATE. "ViewState holds the original property values of every control on a Web Form - before the user made any changes." (http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa051705a.htm) Button clicks and form control contents are transmitted using HTTP POST (post variables) or HTTP GET (query string variables). VIEWSTATE is a hidden form element and is also transmitted so ASP.NET can tell what controls have changed.

Comment: Yes. And in addition to the viewstate parameter posted to the server, notice there is a Button parameter set to Button, indicating which button was pressed (Button1=Button) and Button2=Button in the second case. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Now how does it indicate which event of the button was raised?? Button1=button means clicked. What about setfocus (for example)?

Comment: I guess that for each non-composite ASP .NET control there is only one event **that can be raised from the client side.** The other events, e.g. data binding, are raised from the server side as the Controls are created and data bound. The server is not concerned with set focus or mouse over events. These should be handled on the Client side, using client side technologies like JavaScript.

Comment: and the component that figures all of this out is a HTTP Handler, I assume... Since ASP.NET has to access the information sent by the form .

Answer (score 2):

You must have to read Page Life Cycle of ASP.NET to understand how events in asp.net are raised? Have a look at this article -  [Events in the Page Life Cycle.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Controls that raise events in postbacks must implement `IPostBackEventHandler` and define method RaisePostBackEvent(). The page will try to find the control using its ID, otherwise you have to register the control as requiring an event using `RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent`.

You can read more about this at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequiresraiseevent.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are hidden fields that are populated by the doPostback method, these hidden fields contain the control that was clicked, and various event arguments that get posted back to the form, and then decoded on the server side.

Read this:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Answer (score 0):

## *It's Just HTML!*

Every ASP.NET control is rendered as HTML. A button renders the HTML `<input name="button1" type="submit" />` within a `<form>` element. When the button is clicked, the web browser submits the form to the postback URL along with all the form variables. One of those variables will be "button1" which tells ASP.NET that button1 was clicked and ASP.NET fires the `button1.Click` event.

Please note: There is no ASP.NET magic involved on the user's web browser. Clicking a button on an ASP.NET page is no different than a button on a PHP or ColdFusion page. Everything at the browser end is just HTML. The browser simply submits the form to the server where ASP.NET (or PHP, or ColdFusion) receives the request and determines from the form variables which form elements changed and/or which button was clicked.

Play with this trivial HTML button demo page to see how HTML buttons work:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

## ASP.NET Events

To keep it short-- When you design your page in Visual Studio, somewhere there is a line of code that registers your click handler to the `button1.Click` event. It will look something like this: `Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);`. If your pages use `AutoEventWireup` then this code is generated automatically behind your back.

Either way, when ASP.NET gets the HTML form post that includes button1, then it knows to fire the `button1.Click` event. Your event handler is called because it was pre-registered as above which stores a reference to the event handler method in a list. Every event has a list of methods to call when the event is fired. You can have multiple handlers registered for one event. Each method that is pre-registered is called when an event is fired.